# CodeIgniter URLs help

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-url

I'm planning on re-creating my lyrics website in CodeIgniter.
At the moment, the way I have it set-up is like this:
`example.com/artistname` and `example.com/anotherartist`

I also have `example.com/contact` and `example.com/request` etc..

I can get it to be `example.com/artist/artistname`, but I'd really like to keep it simple for the user to memorize the urls.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks,
Maikel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `application/config/routes.php` try:

```
$route['contact'] = 'contact'; // /contact to contact controller
$route['request'] = 'request'; // /request to request controller
$route['(.*)'] = 'artist/display/$1'; // anything to artist controller, display method with the string as parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Via the CodeIgniter User Guide here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

You can remap anything (`:any`) to your `artist` controller. From there, you can remap `contact`, `request`, etc. to their respective controllers/functions or you can use your Constructor to check for those and call the correct function. Examples:

Using URI Routing:

```
$route['contact'] = "contact";
$route['request'] = "request";
... // etc...
$route['(:any)'] = "artist/lookup/$1"; // MUST be last, or contact and request will be routed as artists.
```

Using your Constructor:

```
public function __construct($uri) {
    if ($uri == "contact") {
        redirect('contact');
    } elseif ($uri == "request") {
        redirect('request');
    }
}
```

This method, however, could result in an infinite loop. I would not suggest it, unless your `contact` and `request` functions were in the same controller. Then you could just call them with `$this->contact()` or `$this->request()` instead of the redirect.

Comment: You still have to pass the name of the artist to the controller function: `$route[':any'] = "artist/lookup/$1";`

Comment: According to the User Guide, you do not. But for the sake of making sure you get what you want, I agree. I'll make the change.

Comment: :any is converted to .+ as routes are basically just regex. If you miss out the () then you cannot use $1. The full route is $route['(:any)'] = "artist/lookup/$1";